# Representing the equation of a line in a variable in Java

Tags: java

I don't think I need code here, but just so you can see what I'm looking at:

```
public class Valuation {

//line is a monotonic (non-decreasing.  Could be constant at points)
//line in 2D space where x=0 -> y=0 and x=1 -> y=1
//the gradient cannot be infinite
//line is only defined between x=0 and x=1.  Can catch when arguments to
//functions are unacceptable given this.
LineEquation line;

float cut(float from, float value){
    //Using 'from' as x, return the least value x' where 'value' is the difference
    //between the y value returned by x and the y value returned by x'
}

float eval(float from, float to){
    //require to > from
    //return the difference between the y value returned by 'to'
    //and the y value returned by 'from'
}
```

The question I have is how do I represent a line/curve like this in Java?  I can verify the lines given fit the requirements that I have, but I want to have this LineEquation class to be able to handle essentially any line that fits these requirements.  These could be quadratic curves or lines where we have something like, when x is between 0 and 0.5, the equation is a, and then when x is between 0.5 and 1, the equation is b.  I got frustrated thinking of all the ways you could describe a line that meets the specifications, and then how I would go through them all, and how I would have to deal with all the different types in different ways.  Unfortunately I do not have the vocabulary to find a library that has what I want.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: My apologies.  I think the entire problem is there though.  I want to know how to represent a line in 2D space in Java.

Comment: Can you provide the mathematical formula for your line?  It's unclear what you mean by "line".

Comment: I meant line or curve I guess.  I see that was very sloppily written.  It's any 2D, continuous 'thing' that can fit the requirements in the first comment block.

Comment: So are you talking about a linear line (y = mx+b) or a quadratic(y = ax^2+bx+c)?

Comment: By "monotonic" do you mean "strictly increasing or strictly decreasing", or do you allow a curve with a constant section?

Comment: And do you expect your code to be able to validate that the function is monotonic and continuous?

Comment: It could be linear or quadratic or anything, so long as it meets those requirements.  By monotonic I meant never decreasing.  It could be constant.  I expect to validate this information, but I may not need to do it in a mathematically complete way.  Everything that gets inputted to this programme will meet the specification.  Any checks will be to make sure that nothing went wrong in the conversion to the form I will have it.

Comment: If you allow constant sections, then your `cut` method isn't clearly specified.  It's possible that a constant section could include the value that the `cut` is trying to reach.  Also, you should probably edit your question to clarify what you mean by "monotonic" - not everyone's going to read into the comments.

Comment: Sure.  It should be the least x'.  I've made some edits.

Comment: OK, incidentally, "constant at points" isn't the same as "constant in sections".  For example, y = x^3 has a point where the gradient is 0, but there's no interval over which it's constant.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Java 8, then probably the simplest thing to do would be to store the curve as a `Function<Float,Float>`, which can implement any kind of equation for any kind of curve, provided `y` is single-valued for any given `x`, and `x` always falls within range for a `float`.

Your class might look like this.

```
public class Valuation {

    final Function<Float,Float> curve;

    public Valuation(final Function<Float,Float> curve) {
        this.curve = curve;
    }

    float eval(float from, float to){
        return curve.apply(to) - curve.apply(from);
    }
}
```

Then you can create these with calls such as

```
new Valuation( x -> ( x * x + 2 * x + 3 ))
```

for a typical monotonic quadratic, or

```
new Valuation( x -> ( x > 0.5 ? 3 * x : 1 + x ))
```

for a piecewise function consisting of two linear sections.

I haven't shown the code for `cut`.  Had to leave something up to you!

Comment: An equation with a constant is just a line.  You may be thinking of `BiFunction<Float, Float, Float>` instead.

Comment: @Makoto No, I mean what I said and I said what I mean.  I am NOT thinking of `BiFunction`.

Comment: A `Function` only takes a single parameter and returns a value.  If you're thinking about the equation of a line, that's Ax+By=C, which requires at least *two* in that context.  I could be wholly misunderstanding something though.

Comment: @Makoto, my understanding of the question is that OP wishes to encapsulate the concept of a curve.  OP said "line", but he/she also clarified that it could include quadratics and/or piecewise-defined functions.  So it's definitely not something of the form `Ax+By=C`.  You have understood the question differently - that's fine, of course, but maybe you could provide your own answer that fits with your understanding.

Comment: This looks so promising!  Thank you!  I'll try to get this to work.  Apologies for making the task more difficult by being imprecise.